# Jar files are not opening

Tags: java, jar

.jar files won't open on my PC. I've tried reinstalling Java and messed with the environment variables.

Comment: is JRE installed?

Comment: "won't open" .... what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: Firstly, JRE is installed, Secondly; all jarfiles simply wont open, through .bat console or clicking, nothing works

Comment: I've also tried Jarfix to no avail

Comment: you mean to say: they don't run? for all we know, they don't have a manifest file, or your environment settings are not set right

Comment: im not sure. How do i check?

Comment: Opening it up as a zip file.with a program like `7-Zip` would be the quickest way.

Comment: Change the .jar extension to .zip and then it can be opened with  any program like 7-zip, winrar etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do all of the following things:

- Ensure that you have JRE installed by entering `java -version` in command prompt.
- Ensure that Java is properly added to the system path. Read about that [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).
- Open your command prompt, navigate to the location of your jar and enter `javaw.exe -jar <yourfile>.jar`
- If you are using a path instead of a jar name make sure you are wrapping it in double quotes.
- Also make sure the jar file is actually present in the directory you are trying to access it from

If that doesn't work please provide additional information about what exactly didn't work.

Comment: this should e comment, not an answer

Comment: That's what I initially wanted to do but I didn't notice that I've just gotten the privilege of posting comments on posts other then mine, it happened quite recently today. I am new to actively participating in this community so out of interest for following SO conventions and rules could you explain though why this should be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: most important reason: it doesn't actually answer the question. it provides a suggestion of what the issue might be, but nothing more. For all we know, his .jar files aren't executables and they can't run.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for. in the future I will use comments to ask for clarification before I post answers to ambiguous questions.

Comment: Okay JRE is installed and the system path is right, When i tried opening a .jar using cmd it came up with this error; Error: Unable to access jarfile "jar here" i tested on multiple jars and all of them came up with this message. (Also since everyone has said something i'm sorry if its an ambiguous question, I've literally just started learning code today and it happens to be the one day java is playing up.)

Comment: If you are using a path instead of a jar name make sure you are wrapping it in double quotes. Also make sure the jar file is actually present in the directory you are trying to access it from.

Comment: Okay, so different programs are now doing different things, one is working, one is a minecraft server and starts up but i cannot access though the game the other is a different minecraft server that does work, eclipse came up with the following error:"A Java Runtime Environment Or Java Develepment Kit must be available in order to run eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin" Rather confused as i have set that as the path in variables and made sure JRE and JDK are installed.

Comment: That's a separate issue and you should create a new question for it, preferably tagging it with `minecraft` or `minecraft-forge`. If the issue has been resolve it would be kind of you to accept my answer, thank you.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. and sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there. Good luck resolving your issue and if you do take my advice to create a new question feel free to post the link here so I can check it out and see if I can help you further.